# Use of setIcon on jLabel repeats old image

Tags: java, swing

I'm attempting to display an image that was downloaded from a website, with the use of `setIcon` and a `jLabel`

```
jLabel5.setIcon(new ImageIcon("image.png"));
```

At the start of the program, the image doesn't exist, it gets downloaded, and after that displayed, with no problems. But if it changes, even if it downloads a newer version of the image, it will display the old one, as if it had a cache of it or something.

Does someone know why this happens? How to get a workaround with or without this method?

I have also tried to do the following to see if it could help, with no success:

```
jLabel5.setIcon(null);
jLabel5.setIcon(new ImageIcon("image.png"));
```

It would display nothing and then the same old image again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it will display the old one, as if it had a cache of it or something.

Yep, caching is the problem. Here are a couple of options:

```
//  This works using ImageIO

imageLabel.setIcon( new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read( new File(imageName) ) ) );

//  Or you can flush the image

ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(imageName);
icon.getImage().flush();
imageLabel.setIcon( icon );
```

Comment: strange why on-memory Object needed that, interesting +1

Comment: Yes! That was definitely the "problem". I haven't tested the first one, but it should probably work as well. I mostly wanted to know why it happened and how to get rid of it. Thanks also to everyone else which gave me answers that helped towards the problem :)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to use the [SwingUtilities.invokeLater()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29) method, similar to this:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() { 
   public void run() {
      //JLabel myLabel = new JLabel("Old Text");
      jLabel5.setIcon(new ImageIcon("image.png"));
   }
});
```

Taken from [here](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090615175506AALayf6).

Comment: No, it didn't help unfortunately. I also tried repainting the component, but I don't think it has any use, given that when I give null it changes it without a problem at all. Thanks

Comment: @Filgera then you have another issue,

Answer (score 2):

If the problem is about caching, try downloading the image with a query string.  For example, http://abc.co.th/image.png?t=149534274  The number is obtained from `System.currentTimeMillis()`

Answer (score 2):

for example

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;

public class LabelsIcon extends JFrame implements Runnable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JLabel label = new JLabel();
    private Random random = new Random();
    private boolean runProcess = true;

    public LabelsIcon() {
        label.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        Dimension d = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(d.width / 3, d.height / 3));
        add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
        new Thread(this).start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (runProcess) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getImage()));
                }
            });
            try {
                Thread.sleep(300);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public BufferedImage getImage() {
        int w = label.getWidth();
        int h = label.getHeight();
        GradientPaint gp = new GradientPaint(0f, 0f, new Color(
                127 + random.nextInt(128),
                127 + random.nextInt(128),
                127 + random.nextInt(128)),
                w, w,
                new Color(random.nextInt(128), random.nextInt(128), random.nextInt(128)));
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D g2d = bi.createGraphics();
        g2d.setPaint(gp);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        return bi;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                LabelsIcon t = new LabelsIcon();
            }
        });
    }
}
```