# Update window every time image gets received

Tags: java, swing, sockets, bufferedimage, concurrency

I'm getting images through sockets. Now, I'm actually getting it, but only once as I expected.

I have checked out some classes you can add events to, such as the *ImageReader* but it wont communicate with my *JFrame*. When I finalize my frame, it doesn't seem to update at all.

Server:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        DefaultWindow window = new DefaultWindow();
        window.frame.setVisible(true);

        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(4305);
        Socket cs = ss.accept(); // only 1 client is assumed

        // this bit should be in some sort of complete event
        BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(cs.getInputStream());

        window.image.setIcon(new ImageIcon(bi));
        window.frame.validate();
        window.frame.repaint();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

What should I do? What's the best practice?

---

**EDIT 11-11-11 16:19**

I have followed mKorbel's answer and it seems to work better, but I'm still getting errors.

My client script:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Socket cs = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 4305);
        OutputStream os = cs.getOutputStream();

        GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        GraphicsDevice[] gs = ge.getScreenDevices();
        BufferedImage[] screenshots = new BufferedImage[gs.length];

        DisplayMode mode;
        Rectangle bounds;

        while(true) {
            try {
                for(int i = 0; i < gs.length; i++)
                {
                    mode = gs[i].getDisplayMode();
                    bounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, mode.getWidth(), mode.getHeight());
                    screenshots[i] = new Robot(gs[i]).createScreenCapture(bounds);
                }

                if(screenshots[0] != null) {
                    ImageIO.write(screenshots[0], "png", os);
                }
                os.flush();

                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (AWTException e) {
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
    } catch(IOException e) {}
}
```

I'm getting an IndexOutOfBoundsException at this line: `ImageIO.write(screenshots[0], "png", os);` where I write the output to the outputstream.

It seems that the while loop just run 3 times. Why just 3 times? And why does it gives an IndexOutOfBoundsException?

---

**EDIT 11-11-11 16:38**

It seems I've sorted it, however, my label won't update. Any idea's?

Server:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        final DefaultWindow window = new DefaultWindow();
        window.frame.setVisible(true);

        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(4305);
        final Socket cs = ss.accept();

        SwingWorker<ImageIcon, Void> sw = new SwingWorker<ImageIcon, Void>() {
            BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(cs.getInputStream());

            BufferedImage bis;
            Graphics2D graphics2D;
            ImageIcon icon = null;

            @Override
            protected ImageIcon doInBackground() throws Exception {
                bis = new BufferedImage(window.image.getWidth(), window.image.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

                graphics2D = bis.createGraphics();
                graphics2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
                graphics2D.drawImage(bi, 0, 0, window.image.getWidth(), window.image.getHeight(), null);
                graphics2D.dispose();

                if(icon != null) {
                    icon.getImage().flush();
                }

                icon = new ImageIcon(bis);
                return icon;
            }

            protected void done() {
                window.image.setIcon(icon);
                window.frame.validate();
                window.frame.repaint();
            }
        };

        sw.execute();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this the client or server?

Comment: This is the server. Notice the `ServerSocket` and the `InputStream` objects. I'll add it anyway

Comment: I see a server accepting connections on port 4035, but I don't see the image being written. Are you getting a valid image in `bi`? Is `window` built on the [event dispatch thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)? An [sscce](http://sscce.org/) might help.

Comment: @trashgod I'm displaying the image in a label (see `window.image.setIcon(icon)`) so there's no need to write anything anywhere. Yeah, the image is valid, because it does show the (first) image (read the question and edit). Finally no, the window is not built on an event dispatch thread.

Comment: `DefaultWindow` is not shown. Swing GUI objects should be constructed and manuipulated _only_ on the [event dispatch thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because you have some issues with [Concurency in Swing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html), put that to the Background Task

- [SwingWorker](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/simple.html), similair example in the tutorial, in this case is GUI still accesible and doesn't waiting for end of Task(s)
- `Runnable#Thread`, but output to the GUI must be wrapped into `invokeLater()`, in this case is GUI still accesible and doesn't waiting for end of Task(s)
- simple wrap that to the `invokeLater()`, but in this case is GUI freeze isn't accesible and  waiting for end of Task(s), but this way is wrong, simply don't do that

put your `BufferedImage` as [Icon](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) to the [JLabel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately I don't see how this is helping me. Sorry

Comment: @Tim S. hmmm http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8084115/use-of-seticon-on-jlabel-repeats-old-image/8084657#8084657

Comment: I think it's my icon cache. Any solutions for that?

Comment: +1 This definitely needs a separate thread for reading; `SwingWorker` is convenient.

Comment: Okay I tried what you said and so far it works, but now I'm getting IndexOutOfBoundsException on my `ImageIO.write()`, although I'm not sure why... See my updated post