# repaint() method won't repaint my screen

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, paint

What I'm trying to do here is call the `repaint()` method from within my `loadbg()` method. However, `repaint()` isn't working, and my image (stored in the var `bg`) won't load onto the screen. Any suggestions as to why this won't work?

```
package core;

/*** @author Adil

 * 2DPlatformer
 * Written by Adil
 * Built upon the player-core framework (written by Adil)
 * GNU Licensed

 */
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

@SuppressWarnings("serial") //Suppress serial warning ID
public class Core extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DisplayMode dm = new DisplayMode(800, 600, 16, 
                DisplayMode.REFRESH_RATE_UNKNOWN); 
        //new display with parameters 800x600 + 16 bit color depth
        Core i = new Core(); //new core class var 
        i.run(dm);
    }
//variables for image loading below
    public Screen s;
    public Image bg;
    public boolean loaded = false;

//run method below
    public void run(DisplayMode dm) {
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        setFont(new Font("Ubuntu", Font.PLAIN, 24));
        s = new Screen();
        loaded = false;
        try {
            s.setScreenSize(dm, this);
            loadbg();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        } finally {
            s.RestoreScreen();
        }
    }

    public void loadbg() {
        bg = new ImageIcon(
                "file:\\\\home\\adil\\Desktop\\pack_2\\bgame.jpg").getImage();
        loaded = true;
        s.repaint();//s is my screen object, but it won't repaint.
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        if (g instanceof Graphics2D) {
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, 
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        }
        if (loaded) {
            g.drawImage(bg, 0, 0, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

1) better way would be put [Icon/ImageIcon](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) to [JLabel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html), rather than paint `Image` by using `paint()`

2) for Swing is there `paintComponent()` instead of `paint()`

3) don't use `Thread.sleep(int)` for Swing GUI use [javax.swing.Timer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) instead, because during `Thread.sleep(int)` you GUI simply freeze, nothing else

Comment: I've tried some other methods, like changing the way the file is drawn and loaded through paintComponent(), doesn't seem to work :|

Comment: check this post is same as you need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8084115/use-of-seticon-on-jlabel-repeats-old-image/8084657#8084657 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943584/update-jlabel-every-x-seconds-from-arraylistlist-java/7944388#7944388

Comment: As I am a noob at Java (learning off a tutorial), how would I go about implementing this? (There was a comment on the tutorial, however, that didn't help at all)

Comment: Pretty sure u don't need to call s.repaint(); u can just call repaint();

Comment: @imulsion in most cases could be contraproductive, because you (maybe) want to repaint only part of visible GUI .... depends of