# JPanel is not refreshing properly

Tags: java, swing

A friend of mine sent me a project and ask me to make it more clean, the project is a JFrame with a Container which has some labels placed by images and they change according to some parameters, what I tried to do was placing all labels into a JPanel in a JFrame, the problem is that labels are not changing, when I fill up the Panel to create the map works fine but when the images has to switch isn't working, the logical is fine becasue I checked it with the logger (System.out.println stuff) and is working properly.
Also I have to say that the JPanel I created was made with the palette of NetBeans (drag and drop).

```
public final void createMap(int map[][]) {
myGrid = new GridLayout(13, 16, 0, 0);
myLabel = new JLabel[13][16];
myPanel.setLayout(myGrid);

//Start doing some stuff to fill my JPanel with labels placing images on them.
//This works fine

 for(int i = 0; ...) {
  for(int j = 0; ...) {
   if(map[i][j]==0) {
    myLabel[i][j].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/ImageA.jpg")));
   }

   if (map[i][j]==1) {
    myLabel[i][j].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/ImageB.jpg")));
   }
   .
   .
   .
   myPanel.add(myLabel[i][j]);
   myPanel.revalidate();
  }
 }
//End doing some stuff
}

//The problem comes here when I try to switch images

public final void play() {

if(something) {
  //The position 2,3 "switches" its image with the position 2,4
  myLabel[2][3].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/ImageA.jpg")));
  myLabel[2][4].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/ImageB.jpg")));
 }
//THIS IS NOT WORKING
myPanel.validate();
}
```

I have tried myPanel.validate, .revalidate(), .repaint() and none works.

Any help is welcome. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Consider creating and posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org). If we can reproduce your problem, we can better be able to help you fix it.

Comment: Maybe this will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8084115/use-of-seticon-on-jlabel-repeats-old-image

Comment: Try using `myPanel.revalidate()` and/or `myPanel.repaint()`

Comment: I have tried to make it the most short and readable possible for the problem I'm having, I'm very sorry I can't post a compiled working code because the code (not mine) is really messed up (the whole program is written in a single class of 2000 lines) I'm not trying to clean code or make a performance just trying to make the UI more friendly to user.

Comment: I have also used revalidate().

Comment: @Blackmore: One of the reasons that we ask for a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) is because sometimes we need more context; for instance, is `play()` being called in the EDT or not, this can cause issues with updating UI components

Comment: The way to create new functionality for your program, especially you don't yet understand well, is to create it in a small isolated test program, so you can work the bugs out of it without worrying about the effects of other portions of your program. I suggest that you do that now, which at the same time will give you an sscce. Failing this, I don't see how we will have much of a chance of being able to help you, and if you can't do this, consider closing this question.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance but, How do I know if my method is called in the EDT?

Comment: `EventQueue.isDispatchingThread()`

Comment: please to see my answer here

Comment: @MadProgrammer I debugged step by step but never found such method, I think I have to read my java for newbies book again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- in some of cases `Icon/ImageIcon` doesn't works (sucked from web or HDD)

.

```
     ImageIcon pictures = new ImageIcon("whatever");
     pictures.getImage().flush();
     myLabel[2][3].setIcon(pictures);
```

.

- solution is very simple, load all Icon/ImageIcon as local variables, then Swing JComponents never caused a.m. issue

Comment: Thanks for the response but it didn't work either.

Comment: then store Icons as local variables

Answer (score 2):

You can update that `JLabel` icon by getting it directly from the `JPanel`. Before you run this code you have to give name to your each `JLabel`.

```
if(something) {
doSomething(myPanel);
}

public void doSomething(JPanel myPanel) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Component[] components = myPanel.getComponents();
                Component component = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < components.length; i++) {
                    component = components[i];
                    if (component instanceof JLabel) {
                        JLabel label = (JLabel) component;
                        String name = label.getName();
                        if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("a")) {
                            label.setIcon(null);
                            label.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/ImageA.jpg")));
                            label.revalidate();
                            label.repaint();
                        }
                    }
                }

                myPanel.revalidate();
                myPanel.repaint();
            }
        });
    }
```