# Update a JLabel with a JButton

Tags: jbutton, jlabel, bufferedimage

In my code I have a JButton (named PlotStatus) that, when clicked, imports and prints inside a JLabel an image. The image is imported as BufferedImage from a png file that is constantly updated. I want to be able to refresh/update the image on the JLabel any time the JButton is clicked. That is, at each click I want the buffer memory to reset and JLabel reload the (updated) image. Instead, I get all different images being printed out, with the first one staying on the foreground.

StatusLabel and temp are defined here as private (but public made no difference).
I have tried many different ways and read numerous posts with absolutely no luck, for something that looks that it should be working. Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

```
        //This is an Item Listener which reacts to clicking on the JButton PlotStatus
    PlotStatus.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {

    JLabel statusLabel = new JLabel(); panel1.remove(statusLabel);
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = null;
    try {   
    bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new File("status.png"));
    bufferedImage.flush();

    JLabel temp = new JLabel();
    temp.setIcon(new ImageIcon(bufferedImage));
    statusLabel = temp;
    panel1.add(statusLabel);    
    revalidate();repaint();

    statusLabel.setVisible(true);statusLabel.setBounds(560,20,650,440); 
    } catch(IOException ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
     }
    });
```

Comment: I applied the suggestions of the (first) answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8084115/use-of-seticon-on-jlabel-repeats-old-image but again it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found the answer myself. Stupidly enough, I had the `JLabel statusLabel = new JLabel();` **inside** the ActionListener. So, any time I would click the button, the action fired would create a new instance of the `JLabel` (and hence the `BufferedImage`) resulting in my swing having a number of JLabels equal to the number of clicks of the JButton! I simply moved  `JLabel statusLabel = new JLabel();` before the line `PlotStatus.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {` and it now works and updates the BufferedImage at each click, as expected.

I hope this will be useful for somebody in the future!